# Why does separating the Sets in this Update increase speed?

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to speed up the following query.

By accident I noticed that if I separate the "Sets" as below, the speed is greatly increased.

That is counter-intuitive to me.

```
UPDATE [Arthur].[ZX].[Orders]  
    SET [Status] = IIF ((SELECT SUM([ExecSignedAmount]) 
                            FROM [Arthur].[ZX].[FilledOrders] 
                            WHERE [Symbol] = [Arthur].[ZX].[Orders].[Symbol] AND [AccountIdent] = [Arthur].[ZX].[Orders].[AccountIdent]) = [Arthur].[ZX].[Orders].[TargetPosition], 'Filled' , 'Working'), 
                        [ExecDate] = '2019-03-02', [ExecUTC] = '12:44:45.8764130', 
                        [ExecSignedAmount] = (SELECT sum([ExecSignedAmount]) FROM [Arthur].[ZX].[FilledOrders] WHERE [OrderID] = 100151), 
                        [ExecPrice] = (SELECT sum([ExecSignedAmount] * [ExecPrice])/ISNULL(NULLIF(sum([ExecSignedAmount]),0),1) 
                                        FROM [Arthur].[ZX].[FilledOrders] WHERE [OrderID] = 100151), 
                        [ExecSettDate] = '2019-03-02', 
                        [DogProvider] = 'DUM' 
                        WHERE [OrderID] = 100151
```

But if I do these 2 separately, with the IIF in own query, I get a 10-fold speed increase!

```
UPDATE [Arthur].[ZX].[Orders]  
SET [ExecDate] = '2019-03-02', [ExecUTC] = '12:44:45.8764130', 
                    [ExecSignedAmount] = (SELECT sum([ExecSignedAmount]) FROM [Arthur].[ZX].[FilledOrders] WHERE [OrderID] = 100151), 
                    [ExecPrice] = (SELECT sum([ExecSignedAmount] * [ExecPrice])/ISNULL(NULLIF(sum([ExecSignedAmount]),0),1) 
                                    FROM [Arthur].[ZX].[FilledOrders] WHERE [OrderID] = 100151), 
                    [ExecSettDate] = '2019-03-02', 
                    [DogProvider] = 'DUM' 
                    WHERE [OrderID] = 100151;

UPDATE [Arthur].[ZX].[Orders]  
SET [Status] = IIF ((SELECT SUM([ExecSignedAmount]) 
                        FROM [Arthur].[ZX].[FilledOrders] 
                        WHERE [Symbol] = [Arthur].[ZX].[Orders].[Symbol] AND [AccountIdent] = [Arthur].[ZX].[Orders].[AccountIdent]) = [Arthur].[ZX].[Orders].[TargetPosition], 'Filled' , 'Working')                   
                    WHERE [OrderID] = 100151
```

I would be grateful for an explanation so I can build better queries in future.

Comment: I suspect due to the number of subqueries you have. If you could do away with those, and use some `JOIN` syntax it would (probably) be even faster. What do the execution plans suggest?

Comment: Maybe execution plans - maybe that you just tested them after doing the initial update so there was no work to do. Impossible to say from here. You should provide a full repro that demonstrates the issue you are asking about

Comment: @Larnu They don't suggest anything! Or perhaps I am looking in the wrong place (Top 2 lines of execution plan tab)?

Comment: @ManInMoon: have you tried the Query analyzer? it is in the query window and able to tell you if there are better queries from yours. aside from that, creating index also speeds up the update query/select statement.

Comment: @Stephanie I just looked up Query Analyser. It seems to be trying to tune my entire DB - I haven't found an example where it gives advice on a single query. How do I do that?

Comment: @ManInMoon: heya just posted my answer. hope u find it helpful. apologies for the delay in response. time difference; i'm in singapore.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (i found this detailed step by step query online),

a) In query window type the update statement.

b) highlight the query and right lick on it.

c) choose Analyze query in database engine tuning advisory

d) Choose the respective database on which the query should be executed.

e) on the top of the window click "Tuning options" and select indexes and indexed views.

f) Click start Analysis just below the view menu.

g) If there is any improvement suggested them click on the action menu and select either script recommendations for later implementing (or) apply recommendations to apply immediatly on the produciton.

Note: IT is better to update the statistics of the  table with full scan before trying the above steps.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/61682da3-110e-47a2-bbbe-37ca82919655/how-to-improve-performance-of-an-update-query?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

[Another helpful link regarding optimizing update query](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-plan/optimizing-update-queries)